# Unexpected "secondary" line number labels in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, linum-mode

In .org files—I've seen it only in a file with over 1k lines—emacs sometimes displays a secondary "line number" next to certain headings, like so:

[image: screenshot]

The left-most gutter is populated by linum+, but the digit 8 on line 7 is what confuses me. The heading has no contents, just an empty line (line 8).

I believe the extra / floating digit gives the *final* line number of the collapsed heading...but what caused the number to show up in the first place? What mode is this coming from? Why doesn't it happen to all headings?

And so on. Thanks!

Comment: Does your problem go away if you use the built-in `linum-mode`, without modifications such as `linum+`?  How about trying `nlinum-mode` written by Stefan, instead of using the built-in `linum-mode`?  Where did you get your `linum+`?

Comment: As it turns out, I actually am using built-in linum-mode, not linum+ after all...

Comment: Other than using `nlinum-mode` by Stefan, you may wish to try manually evaluating `(linum-update-current)` and see if that makes the visual glitch go away.  If it does, then consider figuring out where and when to make those additional calls.  I disable a custom modified version of `linum-mode` in buffers with a lot of code-folding going on (such as `org-mode` buffers), because it creates a significant slow-down in performance.  Long buffers also will result in slow-down due to the function `count-lines`.  There are workarounds, but they are beyond the scope of this thread.

Comment: Switching to `nlinum-mode` solves the issue. Thanks for your help!